# Menu become unresponsive in power builder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

We are facing some wired issue.

After doing some work on application, somehow menu become unresponsive and not performing any action from the menu.

This is windows based application.
We are using power builder 11.5.1 Build 4740

We are using PFC extensively in our application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have one **basic suggestion regarding menus in PowerBuilder**.

Try opening the first level ancestor in the menu editor and change something minor and try saving. See if you receive any errors. The ancestor is probably fine.

**Repeat open and save** for the next descendant menu object until you make it to the last descendant menu object applicable for the case you are encountering. You may reach a level where the menu won't save or a message will be displayed indicating a problem with the menu items. If there are errors fix them. If a message is displayed than PB might fix the problem for you, just try saving again. (pb does sometimes fix inheritance problems when saving but not in full rebuild-- this is something PB developers just work around.).

**Menus are the one area in PB where inheritance is flaky**. You'd think a rebuild-full would solve things like this but it does not. Menus get flaky especially if you have tons of menu items m_1, m_2, etc. for dashes-- I think the compiler gets confused or something.

**Otherwise**, if this isn't the issue you are encountering than I'd ask you what you mean by non-responsive. Is the menu completely locked, like you can't click on "File" to see submenu items below it, or are you able to drill but when clicking the menu item not triggering action on the active window? If the latter put a break point in the menu clicked and the event on window you expect to be triggered and debug the app to see what is going on, if anything.